# I am trying to clone a private repo but it says Repository not found?

Tags: git, github

It says,

> git clone https://github.com/username/component-1-rajeshbasnet01.git
> Cloning into 'component-1-rajeshbasnet01'...
> remote: Repository not found.
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/component-1-rajeshbasnet01.git/' not found

I have tried setting up username, email, password.

Comment: On github, there is a button to copy the http url to clone your repo, were you using this link ?

Comment: If you have not authenticated with github properly, you will get not found even if the URL is correct.

Comment: I am authenticated properly, I am using https link to clone. I tried using different ways to clone. The default one says repo not found while next one says repo exists but you don’t have right access while I am the admin of that repo.

Answer (score 1):

Your GitHub link doesn‘t exist (*404 Not Found*). This mean, you don‘t have access to the repository, or the URL is not correct.

To become access, you must contact the private repository owner, to [invite you as a collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository), that you become access to clone abd change the code.

The safest way to `clone` a repository is to *copy* the URL from GitHub‘s `Code` Button:

[image]

Here is a [precise description](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/cloning-a-repository) how you can clone a repisitory on GitHub.

Comment: My teacher has invited me on this repo. He has created using github classroom. I am an admin of that repo but i am not getting access to that repo.

Comment: Then you have become a invitation mail, right? There you can click "View invitation" Button (displayed green in mail) and by clicking you will navigate to the GitHub Repisitory. Otherwise the teacher havn‘t invite you correct.

Comment: The repo URL have you changed for security reason, right? Or from where you have the URL?

Comment: I created a private repo myself for checking purposes and it also didn't get cloned.

Comment: Then I think it is a password/access problem. Have you store your login data permanently in a *credential helper* and changed the password recently? Try it with `git clone https://username:password@github.com/NAME/repo.git`

Answer (score 0):

In my company we use GitLab and GitHub, so we need to have separate git configs: `.gitconfig-gitlab` and `.gitconfig-github`.

.gitconfig:

```css
[includeIf "gitdir:C:/GIT/gitlab/"]
  path = .gitconfig-gitlab
[includeIf "gitdir:C:/GIT/github/"]
  path = .gitconfig-gitlab
```

I just entered **gitlab** twice, so I needed to update to: `path = .gitconfig-github`.

Hope this helps someone.